# Discord Login API Redirects to a URL with dynamic query string

Tags: discord

**What happens?**

After logging into the website using the Discord API, the user is returned to the Redirect URL.

**What I want to happen**

After logging into the website using the Discord API, the user is returned to the page they were on, including any query strings.
{full url}/post.php?postid={some_post_id}

During my testing of this, it appears the API requires an exact redirect url. But because I am using a postid to load a post, I cannot add all the possible redirect urls? How is this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about storing the url in a cookie, then on the page you redirect to trigger navigation to the url in the cookie?

Comment: Honestly I don't like the cookie solution :/ Keeping the info in the redirect url would be much more consistent.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution should be using the state parameter as described here: [Pass a string through Discord OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858066/pass-a-string-through-discord-oauth)