# Pass a string through Discord OAuth?

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

I was wondering if it was possible to use Discord OAuth (identify scope) while also passing through important supplemental information to the redirect URL.

```
site with [important variable] > oauth page > site that needs [important variable] and oauth result
```

I have tried appending something like ?variable="myString" but it shears off all unnecessary URL parameters other than the OAuth information. Discord OAuth also doesn't really appreciate being in an iframe, so that won't be the solution here.

Comment: So basically you want to pass a string at the start of the authorization process and you want to receive the same string without any changes at your returned URI ? did i understand you correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have written a post regarding this question, you can find it here:

https://levbuchel.com/passing-variables-through-oauth

---

Original answer:

To pass variables through an oAuth process, you should use the `state` oAuth parameter.

First create a Json string with your parameters,

for example `{'first':'111', 'second':'222'}`.

Then encode it to base64 so that it will not be modified when passing as a URL.

Pass this string as a `state` (`api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&state=whatEverYouGotAsState`).

Then you will be able to receive and decode it back on your redirect URI.

Comment: Coming back after more experience, it's worth noting that this is applicable for a wide variety of OAuth services (not just Discord), and is sometimes encouraged for security purposes.